# xpath assertion for jdbc response

Tags: xpath, jdbc

I have query which run in jdbc step in soapui which the result are:

```
<Results>
    <ResultSet fetchSize="128">
        <Row rowNumber="1">
            <MODEL_ID>Deposit</MODEL_ID>
            <VALUE1>1</VALUE1>
            <VALUE2/>
            <VALUE_SET/>
            <SCORE>1.00</SCORE>
        </Row>
        <Row rowNumber="2">
            <MODEL_ID>Deposit</MODEL_ID>
            <VALUE1>2</VALUE1>
            <VALUE2/>
            <VALUE_SET/>
            <SCORE>2.00</SCORE>
        </Row>
```

I want to assert the MODEL_ID under rowNumber="2".

I used this XPath expression: `//*:Results/ResultSet/rowNumber="2"/MODEL_ID`

I got the following error:

> Runtimeexception: Required item type of first operand of '/' is node ();supplied value has item type es:string

Answer (score 1):

```
//*:Results/ResultSet/Row[@rowNumber="2"]/MODEL_ID
```

The `*:Results` part looks a bit suspicious... are namespaces involved?

Comment: i just try it to work as also: //Results/ResultSet/rowNumber="2"/MODEL_ID i am getting same error

Comment: @meitale Sorry, I don't get it. Are you claiming that `//Results/ResultSet/rowNumber="2"/MODEL_ID` works against you sample XML?

Comment: I have JDBC step which in it i am query a table in DB. i am not working against XML but result from DB. The result are: <Results>
    <ResultSet fetchSize="128">
        <Row rowNumber="1">
            <MODEL_ID>Deposit</MODEL_ID>
            <VALUE1>1</VALUE1>
            <VALUE2/>
            <VALUE_SET/>
            <SCORE>1.00</SCORE>
        </Row>
        <Row rowNumber="2">
            <MODEL_ID>Deposit</MODEL_ID>
            <VALUE1>2</VALUE1>
            <VALUE2/>
            <VALUE_SET/>
            <SCORE>2.00</SCORE>
        </Row>
    </ResultSet>
</Results>

Comment: @meitale Yes, I understood that. Did you try the XPath expression from my answer? It is different from the one in your first comment.

Comment: //Results/ResultSet/rowNumber="2"/MODEL_ID  - i am getting same error

Comment: @meitale Once again: it's `.../ResultSet/Row[@rowNumber="2"]/...`, not `.../ResultSet/rowNumber="2"/...`.

Comment: I have new question on it:   <VALUE2/> is null, even if i am telling the expected result is null it say: expecting null actuall null

Answer (score -2):

checked: //Results/ResultSet/Row[2]/MODEL_ID

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?